# Erro na hora de multiplicar 02 campos automaticamente com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o código abaixo do qual multiplica o valor do campo **Valor** com o valor campo **Qtd** e o resultado aparece automaticamente no campo **ValorTotal**. Vejam:

```js
function calcular() {
  var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor').value, 10);
  var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('qtd').value, 10);
  var multiplicar = valor1 * valor2;
  if (multiplicar == 'NaN') {
    document.getElementById('valorTotal').value = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('valorTotal').value = multiplicar;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Valor:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Valor" id="valor" class="form-control" onfocus="calcular()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Qtd:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Qtd" id="qtd" class="form-control" onblur="calcular()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Valor Total:</label>
      <input type="text" name="ValorTotal" id="valorTotal" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O problema é que no campo **valorTotal** estava aparecendo **NaN** antes de digitar no segundo campo e para impedir, criei a condicional no código acima, só que agora não consigo digitar no campo. Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: "só que agora não consigo digitar no campo", isso não parece estar acontecendo no seu código.

Comment: NaN está acontecendo porque você calcula o valor no momento em que o primeiro input ganha foco. Nesse momento não tem valor digitado. Você pode usar o [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que enquanto o campo estiver vazio, o `value` será uma *string* vazia e você está tentando converter uma *string* vazia para decimal, resultando em `NaN`. Veja:

```js
console.log(parseInt('', 10))
```

Então por que não converter para decimal e multiplicar apenas quando possuir os dois valores?

```js
function calcular() {
  var valor = document.getElementById('valor');
  var qtd = document.getElementById('qtd');
  var total = document.getElementById('valorTotal');
  
  if (valor.value && qtd.value) {
    total.value = parseInt(valor.value) * parseInt(qtd.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Valor:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Valor" id="valor" class="form-control" onfocus="calcular()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Qtd:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Qtd" id="qtd" class="form-control" onblur="calcular()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Valor Total:</label>
      <input type="text" name="ValorTotal" id="valorTotal" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fora isso, é um tanto quanto esquisito um campo responder no evento `focus` e outro no `blur`.

Comment: Olá Anderson. Certo. Confesso que não tenho muitas experiências com Javascript. No caso dos campos dos eventos, como eu poderia fazer para corrigir?

Comment: Se quiser atualizar em "tempo real", use o evento `input`; se não, o melhor seria ambos com `blur`, para atualizar apenas quando tirar o foco do campo.

Comment: Perfeito Anderson. Fiz os ajustes conforme você mostrou e funcionou! Muito obrigado mais uma vez!